# Boostrap on tab click keep the first tab contents constant and show some extra fields

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have started learning bootstrap to use it in my project . I have ran into a situation where . I would like to keep the contents of first default tab always available(the tab is always fixed). When the user clicks on second tab i would love to add some more form elements to the existing tab . Now he should not be able to click on the first tab. so when he clicks the second tab again . I should hide the extra contents which i displayed first . I can do this using html and javascript . Do we have something readily available like this in bootstrap , what are the options i can explore to learn more like this .

Comment: Hi. Can you provide some code with what you tried.

Comment: `Now he should not be able to click on the first tab. so when he clicks the second tab again . I should hide the extra contents which i displayed first`, I don't think it's a use case fitting tabs, you would just end up confusing whoever uses your application.